# I'm storing a ViewPager's current item in an Application's subclass field for future reference. Is there a better solution?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a main activity using `BottomNavigationView`, where the first `Fragment` has a nested `ViewPager` with some tabs. When I navigate to the second or third "main fragment" and then go back to the first (the one holding the tabs) I would like to restore the tab that was active when I left.

To achieve this I'm saving the viewPager's current item in the fragment's `onPause`...

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    App.homeTab = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "item: " + App.homeTab);
}
```

being `App.homeTab` a static filed into my `Application`'s subclass:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public static int homeTab = 0;
    // [...]
```

... and then I'm retrieving that value in the fragment's `onCreateView` like this:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
        getContext(), 
        getChildFragmentManager(), 
        HomeCategoryContent.Elements
    );

    viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"restored tab: " + App.homeTab);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(App.homeTab);

    // [...]
```

`SectionsPagerAdapter` extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`, straight from the Android Studio's template.

It works, but somehow I feel a bit uncomfortable every time I have to use a static reference to some UI component...

Are there better solutions?
Is this one prone to memory leakage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` variables are not mandatory in this case. You can store the value everywhere what is still "alive"  for example - activity instance variable. It will look like this

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).setFirstPagerPosition(position)

((MyActivity)getActivity()).getFirstPagerPosition()
```

The better approach is to pass activity to fragment as instance of some interface it will implement like this

```
interface FirstPagerPositionStorage {
    void setFirstPagerPosition(position);

    int getFirstPagerPosition();
}

class MyActivity extends Activity implements FirstPagerPositionStorage{
...
}

MyFragment.newInstance((FirstPagerPositionStorage)this)

class MyFragment extends Fragment {
   FirstPagerPositionStorage listener;

   static MyFragment newInstance(FirstPagerPositionStorage listener){
       MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
       fragment.listener = listener;
       return fragment;
   }

}
```

Don't use `onPause` method to store such values use `OnPageSelectedListener` of `ViewPager` there is a method `onPageSelected(int position)` - use it to store the value

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                listener.setFirstPagerPosition(position);
                //or if you will go with activity methods 
                ((MyActivity)getActivity()).setFirstPagerPosition(position);
            }

        });
```

If you chose listener way don't forget to check if current activity implements this interface in fragments `onAttach` method

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (!(context instanceof FirstPagerPositionStorage)){
        throw IllegalStateException("Activity must implement FirstPagerPositionStorage");
    }

}
```

This was easier and more classic Android way. Modern way is to use shared between all the bottom navigation fragments [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=Cj0KCQjwhtT1BRCiARIsAGlY51KX5Hd67iILSNw7ipfS9zYZKO1M4rwriNdPDl1kWcQ63V2FnVUMdD4aAoC1EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Most of the modern apps will be implemented this way. It is pretty cool to use in conjunction with `Jetpack Navigation` and `BottomNavigation` - more details [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

Either way all the values stored this way will be lost after the activity is closed as well as `static` value will be lost after the app is closed. If you want to persist this value between app runs - use `SharedPreference` or some other storage like file cache or database.

Using `static` variables is not very good but it is not at all bad. The major downfall of this - you can get used to it and eventually the app will become much harder to maintain due to the lack of proper dataflow.

Hope it helps

Comment: Definitely. I'll dig ASAP into all the stuff you carefully packed in this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Being the project born on top of the A.Studio bottom navigation's template, I already had the `PageViewModel` and it was storing the index correctly in every `DetailFragement`'s `onCreate`. I added to it also the `getIndex()` method  and called it after setting the viewPager adapter (although upon 1st opening it's null). It works. Thanks again.